# Can we insert elements of multiple types in a List?

Tags: java

While working on a program, I thought if it is possible to add elements of multiple types e.g. Integer, String, Long etc in a List, without making it to accept everything of Object type.

I want to restrict the list to accept elements of only these three types? Is this possible?

There are few solutions of it, which I dont want to do

1) We can create a Pojo having all these three types as elements and insert that pojo.

2) A base class implementing datatype specific wrapper classes. In this case, user will know this abstraction while creating objects of different classes.

Can this be done in a better and more generic way?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? One day, someone may have to come behind you and have to read and understand your code. I'm struggling to think of a good reason to do this.

Comment: Another option - wrap a List<Object> as a private implementation detail in an outer class that provides an API to put only Integer, String and Long.

Comment: @AndyThomas While technically true, that's just a workaround to what is almost definitely a terrible design

Comment: @Michael - We don't know the OP's requirements. I don't think we have enough information to judge the OP's design. Sometimes it's useful to provide an actual answer to the question, even if there are open questions about the design.

Comment: Strings and numbers are obviously different things. There is *nothing* I can conceive of that should not care whether you have one or the other. If the strings contain numbers, they should be parsed and converted first. If the numbers represent strings, what the hell is going on? It's got nothing to do with specific requirements.

Comment: Hey Guys! I know it is definitely a terrible design, but still was thinking if there is any way this can be done. Appreciate the suggestions that you gave. Andy! your suggestion is definitely better than what I mentioned as option 2 in my question, but It will be the same if I have a class with class member as a List<Object>, and add methods specific to the data type I want. For rest, it will throw back UnsupportedTypeException. Wont that be better?

Comment: @Devil - You control the outer class. You could implement java.util.List, and throw a RuntimeException for disallowed types. (Note that UnsupportedTypeException is *not* a RuntimeException.) Better yet, you could *not* implement List, which specifies a contract you may not be able to support, and instead provide exactly the API you want. Regardless, you know your requirements best.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do as an alternative, is implement your own type of collection. This could have 3 `add`-methods accepting the different kinds of types you want and the default `add`-method should throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

This however might not be the ideal solution, since it might introduce bugs if you don't have a full understanding of how the collection you are implementing/extending should work internally.

Comment: And so what is his remove method going to look like? Seems like there will be just 3 separate lists underneath the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You have **Number** to use with, well, any kind of number.

But there is no relationship between String and Number.

So, `List<Object>` is your only choice there.

And keep in mind: when you really have to deal with different types of elements - maybe List isn't the correct abstraction to use?!

In other words: if you have values of different types that belong together, you should rather consider creating a specific class to wrap around those values.

Comment: Correction: `List<Object>` is not your only choice. Rethinking your design so that you don't have a `List<RandomCrap>` is another.

Comment: That part I already added in. What are alternatives to `List<Object>` ... `List<?>` ?

Comment: Hm, not really. You can't instantiate something with `<?>`

Comment: If I create a separate class containing class variables with these three dataTypes, while creating an object of this class, I will be providing concrete value of only one of these members. So, while traversing the list, I would have to manually check what member has the default value and what does not. That will not be an ideal thing to do, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to use `Map<TypeOfData, List<Type>>` rather than hacking `List` to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are probably some hacked together work-around that may help you do this, the simple answer to your question is "no, this can't be done". Part of programming is using the right tool for the right job. In this case, it's almost certain that a List is the wrong tool to help you do this job.